# Local images load after delay when using React in .Net Core

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a React App hosted in .Net Core Back-End using the template offered by Visual Studio.

Eventually, I've encountered a strange behavior: when a component with an image, saved locally, renders for the first time, the image gets displayed after a delay of about 1/2 seconds. The next time, the component renders normally with the image already displayed.

This problem doesn't happen when I use images from the Internet. So for example:

```
<img src="www.google.com/example.png" alt="random image">
```

the image loads instantly.

Additional info is that this issue happens when I launch the React app along with the .Net Core server so they share the same port.
When I launch the Front-End using npm start, the images load instantly, or very rarely they have a noticeable delay.

The images are .jpg and .png from 15kb to 60kb.

I tried:

Storing the images in React's public folder,

Inserting the URL directly in the src attribute:

```
<img src="images/example.jpg" alt="test pic" />
```

Storing them in React's src folder,

Importing the image and then using the reference in the src attribute:

```
import myImage from "../images/example.jpg";

<img src={myImage} alt="test pic" />
```

Nothing solved the issue... is this a problem of how .Net Core manages a React app?

I need to use the application even without an Internet connection so I have to rely on local assets.

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an application-specific issue.

One way would be to maybe look at SSR and rendering out the HTML mark-up on page load.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering

This will help you diagnose if the issue is with your component code, or, an application configuration issue

aSync loading images will probably give you a performance boost if it is below the folder.  Do you use any lazy-loading frameworks, code in your solution - like react-lazy-load-image?  This might be kicking in and causing the delay

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer. No, I don't use any lazy-loading frameworks. For now, I prefer to solve the problem keeping the Client Side Rendering feature before going for the Server Side Rendering route

Comment: if the images load instantly on npm start, are you caching them locally, if not should you be?I had this issue when using a third-party framework, Qubit.  It ran blocking which caused a few second delays during render() and images rendering.  Look int the waterfall tool in Chrome to look for blocking requests